# Primefaces dialog is rendering twice

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, dialog, primefaces, modal-dialog

I've created an ui:component to use like a popup, so I can create a lot of popups using the standard of this template.
The component is just a popup with two buttons (cancel and submit) and a content that can be overriden, like you can see here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
<ui:component>
<p:dialog widgetVar="#{idPopup}" id="#{idPopup}" modal="#{popup.modal}"
    draggable="#{popup.modal}"
    rendered="#{popup.visivel}" visible="#{popup.visivel}"
    closeOnEscape="false" closable="false" header="#{titulo}"
    resizable="false" styleClass="autoWidthDialog" showEffect="fade"
    hideEffect="fade">
    <h:panelGroup style="width:100%">
        <p:focus />
        <ui:insert name="conteudo">Nenhum conteúdo definido!</ui:insert>
        <h:panelGrid id="#{idPopup}PainelMensagens" style="width:100%">
            <p:messages />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <ui:insert name="barraDeBotoes">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="width:100%">
                <p:commandButton value="CANCELAR" immediate="true" update="@form"
                    style="float:right" action="#{controladorPopup.fechar}"
                    onclick="#{idPopup}.hide();" />
                <p:commandButton value="OK" style="float:right"
                    update="@form formAlerta"
                    action="#{controladorPopup.submit}"
                    process="@form" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </ui:insert>
    </h:panelGroup>
</p:dialog>
</ui:component>
</html>
```

The problem happen when I try to submit the form without filling the required fields. The correct behavior is just show again the popup with messages, but the dialog is rendered twice, one with the messages and one without the messages.
You can see this behavior here:

[image: twice rendering]

this is one use of this template:

```
<ui:composition template="../templates/popupSubmit.xhtml">
<ui:param name="titulo" value="Buscar pessoa" />
<ui:param name="popup" value="#{modeloPopupBuscaPessoa}" />
<ui:param name="controladorPopup"
    value="#{controladorPopupBuscaPessoa}" />
<ui:define name="conteudo">
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel value="Tipo de cadastro:" style="float:none" />
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{controladorSugestaoPessoa.tipoCadastro}"
                immediate="true">
                <f:selectItems value="#{carregadorTipoCadastro.itens}" />
                <f:ajax event="change" immediate="true" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:outputText value="Buscar por:" />
        <h:selectOneRadio value="#{controladorSugestaoPessoa.tipoBusca}"
            immediate="true">
            <f:selectItems value="#{carregadorTipoBuscaPessoa.itens}" />
            <f:ajax event="change" immediate="true" />
        </h:selectOneRadio>
        <p:autoComplete value="#{modeloPopupBuscaPessoa.itemSelecionado}"
            forceSelection="true" maxResults="10" queryDelay="500" 
            completeMethod="#{controladorSugestaoPessoa.atualizarSugestoes}"
            var="pessoa" itemLabel="#{pessoa.label}" itemValue="#{pessoa}"
            converter="#{conversorSelectItem}" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

And these are some use:

```
<h:form id="cadastroPessoa">
    <ui:include
        src="resources/components/popups/modulo_cadastro/popupNovoCadastroPessoa.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="idPopup" value="popupNovoCadastroPessoa" />
    </ui:include>
    <ui:include
        src="resources/components/popups/modulo_cadastro/popupCadastroPessoa.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="idPopup" value="popupEdicaoCadastroPessoa" />
    </ui:include>
    <ui:include
        src="resources/components/popups/modulo_cadastro/popupBuscaPessoa.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="idPopup" value="popupBuscaCadastroPessoa" />
    </ui:include>
</h:form>

<h:form id="cadastroProduto">
    <ui:include
        src="resources/components/popups/modulo_cadastro/popupCadastroProduto.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="idPopup" value="popupNovoCadastroProduto" />
    </ui:include>
</h:form>
```

Could someone tell me why this is happening??

Comment: Can you also post the code in the template and template-client that relates to this fragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case I cannot user oncompleteI) method to hide the dialog because it has to be closed to some business logic.

I my case I have use primefaces tabs on UI. Every time I navigate the tabs and then click on button on which dialog appears then my dialogs number are increasing proportionality 
So I have used simple jquery script to remove all the duplication dialog from the UI
e UI.

```
function removeDuplicateDialogs(dialogId) {

    \\ generally all our components have : character we have to 
    \\ replace ':' with '\\:'(applying escape character)
    dialogId = dialogId.replace(/\:/g, '\\:');

    var dialogs = jQuery("div[id=" + dialogId + "]");
    var numOfDialogs = dialogs.length;
    numOfDialogs = numOfDialogs - 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfDialogs; i++) {
        jQuery(dialogs[i]).remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which event are you calling the script on?

Answer (score 4):

I've posted the same question in primefaces forum (like Tommy Chan told), and someone answered this:

> You are probably placing your dialog in the form you are updating which is a nono. Never update the dialog only the stuff in the dialog

I've tried to do this until I saw all my dialogs have "rendered" attribute coming from server (just see the first xml), I have a lot of dialogs in this application and some of them have relation with others (on server), these last are on the same form.

I did something different, I only created this javascript code:

```
function removerDialogo(id) {
   setTimeout(function() {
       removerDialogoAposIntervalo(id);
   }, 100);  
}

function removerDialogoAposIntervalo(id) { 
   id = id.replace(':', '\\:');
   jQuery('div.ui-dialog')
       .find('#' + id)
       .parent().eq(1)
       .remove(); 
}
```

and called this on dialog "onShow" attribute:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="#{idPopup}" id="#{idPopup}" modal="#{popup.modal}"
    draggable="#{popup.modal}" rendered="#{popup.visivel}"
    visible="#{popup.visivel}" closeOnEscape="false" closable="false"
    header="#{titulo}" resizable="false" styleClass="autoWidthDialog"
    showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" onShow="removerDialogo(this.id)">
```

I don't like to do things like this, but I can't find a better way to solve this...
If someone give me a better solution, I will be grateful

Comment: Ha! That was my comment on the primefaces forum. (Lyrionus right? ;)) the reason i said that was because your updates say @form... and your dialog hasn't a form tag around it... so that means its above your dialog... which means your dialog is in the form.

Comment: Fixed with this answer, in my case i was updating all the form instead of just the component. causing the dialog to appear twice.

Answer (score 1):

As I said on the Primefaces forum, you are updating your forms with the dialog in it... you need to place your dialogs out of your form and update them separately.

If you need to use a form in your dialog then place it in your dialog:

```xml
<p:dialog>
  <p:form> 
  </p:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Hi Rafael, as I told, I tried this approach, but the application is very big and this approach can't be used with that composition in a generic way. This is because of the relation of some dialogs. To do this I need to change all application logic... But certainly I will implement in the correct way the next time :) Thanks.

Comment: @brevleq Ahh didn't see that, have you tried instead of placing the renderers on your dialog, placing it in the panelgrid. I know it's a crappy solution but i can't think of anything better at the moment :p

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a dialog, and the solution was placed in the update of the commandButton that shows the dialog component the specific id of the Dialog Component, not the form id.

The solution looks like this:

```xml
<p:dialog id="dialogId">
    <p:commandButton value="OK" style="float:right"
         update="@form dialogId"
         action="#{controladorPopup.submit}"
         process="@form"/>
</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check that your widgetVar="#{idPopup}" id="#{idPopup}" is the same before you submit and after you submit the form. Maybe it has changed and primefaces thinks it doesn't exist anymore and creates a new one.

Comment: the id of the two dialog are the same: cadastroEmpresa:popupNovoCadastroEmpresa

Comment: perhaps ask a question on the primefaces forum...users there are very responsive.

Comment: PrimeFaces widgetVar and JSF id **must not** be the same. I read that "golden" rule in a posting by Optimus himself somewhere in the forums.  Can't find it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `oncomplete` attribute to your submit button and let it hide the dialog:

```
<p:commandButton value="OK" style="float:right"
                 update="@form formAlerta"
                 action="#{controladorPopup.submit}"
                 process="@form"
                 oncomplete="#{idPopup}.hide();"/>
```

Comment: I've already tried this option, the dialog open twice but they are closed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

putting the forms inside dialog isnt the best way to solve it, if you access your application with IExplorer, dialogs wont work with this approach

Comment: Something similar is happening to me, im using ajax to send forms content and every time i click on the button that shows me the dialog, it will render as many dialogs as submits via ajax ive made, i have seen that if i refresh the whole page, it will start again (rendering 1 dialog, 2, 3, etc)

Answer (score 0):

This is an awful bug with no official answer...

I'm using a dialog to render a Google map. The way I handle the bug (using JQuery) is by counting the number of ".map" elements in the DOM on primefaces:dialog.onShow... I then select the :last .map instance rendered (or in your case, whatever content class you're working with), and .remove() the dialog which contains it:

Markup (approx):

```
<pri:dialog onShow="popupOpen();" etc...>
    <div id="map" class"map"></div>
</pri:dialog>
```

JavaScript:

```
function onShowDialog(){
    if($(".map").length > 1){
        $cull = $(".map:last");
        $cull.closest(".ui-dialog").remove();
    }
}
```

If you're a sadist you could, quite comfortably, make that a one liner... I see this as a Primefaces bug. The close button should outright destroy the dialog.